# Local Search Operators Python wrapper Google or-tools

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools, google-local-search

can someone give me an example of how one can access and use the LocalSearchOperator subclasses from the Python wrapper?

Concretely, I'm looking for an example similar to jobshop_heuristic.cc fount at:

http://www.lia.disi.unibo.it/Staff/MicheleLombardi/or-tools-doc/user_manual/manual/metaheuristics/jobshop_lns.html#a-heuristic-to-solve-the-job-shop-problem

but translated into Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at LsApi.java example.

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/java/LsApi.java